# Understanding Information Flow in Tornado App

Tags: python, web-applications, tornado

I'm teaching myself Tornado, so I bought a copy of [Introduction to Tornado](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007NHKVL6), and started working through the examples. I'm onto the third one, and it works, but I don't understand how/why.

Below is a modified, but functionally equivalent, version of the code in the book. I have a file called poemaker.py

```
import os.path
import tornado.web
from tornado.options import define, options


define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('index.html')


class PoemPageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        name = self.get_argument('name')
        noun1 = self.get_argument('noun1')
        noun2 = self.get_argument('noun2')
        verb = self.get_argument('verb')
        self.render('poem.html', mary=name, lamb=noun1, snow=noun2,
                    go=verb)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import tornado.httpserver
    import tornado.ioloop
    import tornado.options

    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    app = tornado.web.Application(
    handlers=[(r'/', IndexHandler), (r'/poem', PoemPageHandler)],
    template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
    )

    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Then in the same directory I have another directory called `templates` which has two html files: index.html and poem.hmtl.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head><title>Poem Maker Pro</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Enter terms below.</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/poem">
            <p>Name<br><input type="text" name="name"></p>
            <p>Singular noun<br><input type="text" name="noun1"></p>
            <p>Singualr noun<br><input type="text" name="noun2"></p>
            <p>Verb w/o object<br><input type="text" name="verb"></p>
            <input type="submit">
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I start the server, and go to `http://localhost:8000/`, I see the contents of index.html rendered. Which is exactly what I would expect, because that's what `IndexHandler` should be doing.

When I fill in the form, and hit submit, I get taken to `http://localhost:8000/poem` which has my poem. So the app works.

What I don't understand is the step in the middle. What's going when I hit submit? How does the application know that submitting the form should me to `http://localhost:8000/poem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, on your example you have setup a RESTful service using tornado.

On the HTML form you have [specify](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp), with `method="post"`, that on submitting the form you will send the data in the fields as HTTP post request. Also by using `action="/poem"` you specify where to send the form-data when a form is submitted.

When you hit submit,you sends a HTTP post request to your tornado web server. When your Tornado server receives the request, Tornado iterates over the `handlers` list and creates an instance of the `tornado.web.RequestHandler` subclass, `PoemPageHandler`, which is associated with the regular expression `"/poem"` which defined in the form as action, and then calls the post() method.

The last command of the post() method is [render](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.render): `self.render('poem.html', mary=name, lamb=noun1, snow=noun2, go=verb)` which renders the template `poem.html` with the parameters passed and redirect you to `http://localhost:8000/poem`.

Comment: Oh, so the problem is that I'm an idiot! Yes, the `action="/poem"` was the part I was missing.